# Is there a way to get a callback from JUnit5 if a test is timed out?

Tags: java, timeout, junit5

In JUnit 4, we used to have to use a `Timeout` rule which we would explicitly put on a test if we wanted it to time out. (In reality we ended up putting this on the base class for all tests, because we always want tests to time out.)

This led to us eventually customising the `Timeout` rule such that before it interrupted the test, it recorded its stack trace.

In JUnit 5, timeouts are now always active (hooray), but I'm thinking about how we would add in recording of the stack trace before the test is timed out.

Is there some kind of intercept point or extension which is called *before* the test is timed out, which we could hook in at to record additional information?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any way to do something immediately *before* the test is timed out, but you can implement a `TestExecutionExceptionHandler` that checks for a `TimeoutException` and do something with that.

For example, you could analyze/print the *suppressed* `InterruptedException` in the `TimeoutException` as follows.

```
class TimedOutTests {

    @RegisterExtension
    TestExecutionExceptionHandler timeoutExceptionHandler = (context, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException && throwable.getSuppressed().length > 0
                && throwable.getSuppressed()[0] instanceof InterruptedException) {
            throwable.getSuppressed()[0].printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        throw throwable;
    };

    @Test
    @Timeout(value = 100, unit = MILLISECONDS)
    void takesTooLong() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

}
```

For further details, feel free to consult the implementation of `org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutInvocation`.

Comment: Actually, in this situation, because the `InterruptedException` is already included in the stack trace, I don't need to do anything at all because the useful information is already there. But sometimes you don't get an `InterruptedException` - you might get a different exception or a null return. And sometimes by the time the code stops it's in a completely different stack. So our code for JUnit 4 records the stack _before_ calling interrupt on the thread.

I suppose I might be able to work behaviour like ours into JUnit 5 itself and then see what my chance is of getting a pull request in.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looking forward to seeing what you come up with in terms of a PR.